# How do I make Firefox stop popping up alerts whenever I finish a download?

Tags: firefox, download, notifications

How do I make Firefox stop popping up alerts whenever I finish a download? I mean the alert you get when all downloads are complete, you get a pop-up/alert/notification that says, "All downloads completed". It has annoyed me for quite a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what worked for me!

- Go to the Firefox special link `about:config` (open a new tab, type in `about:config` into the address bar, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)
- Click the "I'll Be Careful, I Promise!" button
- Type in `browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete` into the search box
- Toggle it to the value of `false` (unless it is already `false`, and then you are already good to go)
- Enjoy alert-free downloading!!